# How to ignore text within one class while extracting data from website Python

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to extract comments from the website and whenever there is a reply to the comment the previous post is included in the comments. I am trying to ignore those replies while extracting

```
url = "https://www.f150forum.com/f118/do-all-2018-f150-trucks-come-adaptive-cruise-control-369065/index2/"
page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')

comments_lst= soup.findAll('div',attrs={"class":"ism-true"})
comments =[]
for item in comments_lst:
    result = [item.get_text(strip=True, separator=" ")]
    comments.append(result)
quotes = []
for item in soup.findAll('div',attrs={"class":"panel alt2"}):
    result = [item.get_text(strip=True, separator=" ")]
    quotes.append(result)
```

For the final result I do not want data from quotes list to be included in my comments. I tried using if but it gives incorrect result.

Example comments[6] gives below result

```
'Quote: Originally Posted by jeff_the_pilot What the difference between adaptive cruise control on 2018 versus 2017? I believe mine brakes if I encroach another vehicle. It will work in stop and go traffic!'
```

my expected result

```
It will work in stop and go traffic!
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add some logic to take out the text contained in divs with class `panel alt2`:

```
comments =[]
for item in comments_lst:
    result = [item.get_text(strip=True, separator=" ")]
    if div := item.find('div', class_="panel alt2"):
        result[0] = ' '.join(result[0].split(div.text.split()[-1])[1:])
    comments.append(result)

>>> comments[6]
[' It will work in stop and go traffic!']
```

Comment: It says invalid syntax near ":=" I tried using "!=" instead it throws an error saying that  "name 'div' is not defined"

Comment: @anonymous13 whoops, I was using python3.8 syntax. You can replace that with `div = item.find('div', class_="panel alt2")`
and then
`if div:`

Answer (score 0):

This will get all messages without Quotes:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.f150forum.com/f118/do-all-2018-f150-trucks-come-adaptive-cruise-control-369065/index2/"

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, 'html.parser')

msgs = []
for msg in soup.select('[id^="post_message_"]'):
    for div in msg.select('div:has(> div > label:contains("Quote:"))'):
        div.extract()
    msgs.append( msg.get_text(strip=True, separator='\n') )

#print(msgs) # <-- uncomment to see all messages without Quoted messages

print(msgs[6])
```

Prints:

```
It will work in stop and go traffic!
```